# How to count relations while paginating?

Tags: laravel

I have these tables:

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
});
```

```php
Schema::create('periods', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->datetime('start_time');
    $table->datetime('end_time');
    $table->datetime('payout_time');
});
```

```php
Schema::create('payouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('period_id');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('period_id')->references('id')->on('periods');
});
```

I am trying to list all the periods with the **total number of users who has a payouts records**, and the **total number of users who doesn't have a payouts records** for each period.

`Period::paginate();`

I have tried to setup HasMany relation in the period table but I am pretty sure I am doing this the wrong way. How can I solve this?

Comment: You answer is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: ok, u'r welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead of `hasMany`

In User Model:

```php
    public function periods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Period', 'payouts', 'user_id', 'period_id');
    }
```

In Period Model:

```php
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'payouts', 'period_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

And get the count like this:

```php
Period::whereHas('users')->withCount('users')->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the relationship that you're looking for is that a `User` hasMany `Payouts` and a `Period` hasMany `Users`. This results in the following query:

```
Period::whereHas(['users' => function ($q) {
    $q->whereHas('payouts');
}])->withCount('users')->paginate();
```

Conversely, if you wish to know about all the Payouts for Users within a given period:

```
Payout::whereHas(['period' => function ($q) use ($start_time, $end_time, $payout_time) {
    $q->where(compact('start_time', 'end_time', 'payout_time'));
}])->withCount('users')->paginate();
```

Comment: What do you mean by a `Period hasMany Users` there is no period_id in users table? or did I understand this wrong?